# Efficient way to replace strings in a list of lists based on a dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, scikit-learn

I have a list of lists that contain classificatory labels for a certain domain. Example:

```
data = [
    ['polmone', 'linfonodi'],
    ['osso'],
    ['polmone'],
    ['linfonodi', 'osso', 'polmone'],
    ['peritoneo', 'osso'],
    ['fegato'],
    ['polmone', 'linfonodi'],
    ['osso'],
    ['osso', 'fegato'],
]
```

The list has 331 lists and each of them can contain one or all the possible labels. The number of possible labels is 20.

I need to feed the list of lists of labels to a `sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier` and was thinking of converting each possible label to a number (e.g. 0-19).

I was wondering about a most efficient way to perform this conversion.

I guess the 'stupid' way could be that of creating a dictionary with each unique label and the corresponding value, as in:

```
{'polmone': 0, 'linfonodi': 1, ..., 'label_19': 19}
```

...and then iterate over each element of the list and perform a `str.replace()`.

I feel there should be a more efficient solution. Do you advice any?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I searched for a similar topic, but couldn't find one. If I mistakenly didn't notice it, feel free to close this thread and send me to hell.

**Edit:**

First of all, I'd like to thank everyone for their answers, as every one of them has come to help for different issues I was encountering and I will encounter.

Now I want to share another solution I just found when dealing with `KNeighborClassifier` and a multiple-output target.
By feeding the encoded labels (both as strings or as integers, and both as simple lists or as numpy arrays), I had the following error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "embedding_gensim.py", line 111, in <module>
    neigh.fit(doc_train, labls_train)
  File "/home/matteo/anaconda3/envs/deep_l/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/base.py", line 906, in fit
    check_classification_targets(y)
  File "/home/matteo/anaconda3/envs/deep_l/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py", line 169, in check_classification_targets
    raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'
```

I found that `MultiLabelBinarizer` solves the problem of feeding the classifier with a multi-label list of lists (or numpy arrays).

So, following @Alexander Rossa's solution:

```py
binarized_labels = MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(encoded_labels_list)
```

binarized_labels then is like:

```py
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
...
```

The `MultiLabelBinarizer()` actually works directly with the lists of strings in `split_labels` .
Perhaps I am tackling the problem from the wrong perspective.

Comment: For this small number of lists and labels this simple straightforward solution is perfectly ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is use a `LabelEncoder` to create the dictionary:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
labels = ['polmone', 'fegato', 'linfonodi']
encoded_labels = label_encoder.fit_transform(labels)
labels_dict = {}
for i in range(len(labels)):
    labels_dict[labels[i]] = encoded_labels[i]

print(labels_dict)
```

That gives you `{'polmone': 2, 'fegato': 0, 'linfonodi': 1}`.

This can be especially helpful when you have many more labels to encode and replace and doing this by hand is not feasible.

Your whole solution can then look something like this:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

data = [
    ['polmone', 'linfonodi'],
    ['osso'],
    ['polmone'],
    ['linfonodi', 'osso', 'polmone'],
    ['peritoneo', 'osso'],
    ['fegato'],
    ['polmone', 'linfonodi'],
    ['osso'],
    ['osso', 'fegato'],
]

# get labels programatically from your data
labels = []
for nested_list in data:
    for label in nested_list:
        if label not in labels:
            labels.append(label)

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoded_labels = label_encoder.fit_transform(labels)
labels_dict = {}
for i in range(len(labels)):
    labels_dict[labels[i]] = encoded_labels[i]

encoded_data = []
for labels_list in data:
    # for each label in a nested list replace it with the encoded value from dict
    encoded_data_list = [l.replace(l, str(labels_dict[l])) for l in labels_list]
    encoded_data.append(encoded_data_list)
```

The encoded data for the data you supplied will look like this:

```
>>> encoded_data
[['4', '1'], ['2'], ['4'], ['1', '2', '4'], ['3', '2'], ['0'], ['4', '1'], ['2'], ['2', '0']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply!
This is very very helpful :)

Comment: @matteozampieri No problem, glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

pandas.factorize( ['B', 'C', 'D', 'B'] )[0]

Output:

[0, 1, 2, 0]

Try to look up at hot encoding as well and tranforming categorical into numeric.

Comment: This is very helpful also for other things I am doing with Pandas. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yay, i'm so happy I was able to help! If you could accept my answer I'd be really greatful(:

Answer (score 1):

I think that a [Label encoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) is what you need.

As specified in the doc this lib transfrom efficiently your labels in an integer sequence.

What you should do is something like:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
labelencoder.fit(["label1", "label2", ...])
for curr_labels_list in all_labels_list:
    res = labelencoder.fit_transform(curr_labels_list)
```